# Flying from the US to Canada with a connection in Montreal, will I need to clear security after clearing customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, montreal

The last time I had to clear customs in YUL (Montreal), I also had to go through the domestic departures security line.  The wording on [the airport's website](https://www.admtl.com/en/guide/connecting-flights) seems to indicate that this procedure has changed in the past few years, and I can remain in the secure area of the terminal in order to make my connecting (domestic) flight.  Is this the case?  I should also note that on my last trip through YUL, I was arriving from an overseas (and non-EU) country, which apparently still need to go through the normal security screening after customs.

It is likely that I'll also be bringing some duty free alcohol back with me, but my understanding from [this page](https://www.admtl.com/en/guide/luggages-security) is that, should I need to clear security again, it will not be an issue to have that in my carry-on baggage (I do not plan to bring a checked bag with me on this trip).

Comment: For the last paragraph, make sure you get that duty-free alcohol in the sealed red taped bag

Comment: I transferred from NY to Addis Ababa in 2016, and there was a small immigration checkpoint at the end of a narrow corridor that allowed me to make the transfer without having to pick up my bags or re-clear security.  It just deposited me into the secure waiting area for departing passengers.  I'm not posting an answer as that was now several years ago and it was also in Toronto.

Comment: @phoog I've cleared customs in both YYZ and YUL before and they've always been slightly different.  Your experience is also special since you weren't connecting domestically.

Comment: Ah, good point, I wasn't paying very close attention so I thought this question was about an international-to-international connection.  :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you only have to clear customs.  When connecting to another flight in YUL, you will bypass the main customs hall and be directed to another customs hall.  As of June 2023, there still seems to be some ongoing work, especially regarding wayfinding and final construction of corridors.  For passengers arriving from the US or EU, duty-free alcohol will not be an issue as you will have already cleared security.

The only exception to this would be if you have to retrieve your checked baggage as that is still done at the edge of the customs area for the main customs hall. You would only need to do this if your baggage won't be transferred automatically.